# Spring Data JPA bulk insertion using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to perform the bulk insertion using Spring Data JPA. I have used the save method of the CrudRepository . But it iterate over the collection and insert every row in database . It doesn't perform the bulk update .I can able to see the 100 insert statement for the following code.

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    for(int i =1; i<= 100; i++){
        customers.add(new Customer("John","Developer");
        if(i % 10 == 0){
            customerRepo.save(customers);
            customers.clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The JPA engine is the one (if configured correctly) using batch updates. Spring-data-jpa is just a thin wrapper.

Comment: what configuration I need to include to perform the batch insertion in spring-data-jpa

Comment: Again, spring-data-jpa is not what you must configure. The underlying JPA engine (hibernate? eclipselink?) is. Read the documentation of the engine you're using.